# How to incorporate the customers leaving (addition of new ones) in the measurement of treatment effectiveness?

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, treatment-effect, control-group, number-needed-to-treat

Consider I have taken a random sample for forming control group in month of January with sample size 5k and treatment group size being 95k.

I am Sending offers to treatment group which are intend to increase the purchasing capacity of the customers.

At every month end I am computing the effectiveness of treatment by computing:

```
(Average purchases of target group - Average purchases of control group) * Target Group size
```

Now Consider every month there people leaving from the target and control group also, people are getting added every month. So, I have two questions:

1. How do I make changes to the Control group to be able to compute uplift accurately?
2. What should be the validity (expiry) of control group/ when should I refresh my control group?

Comment: Regardless of when they are assigned to control or treatment, do they only get one offer (or no offer for the control)? Or is it the case that the same individual can revive the offer one month and not the next month (i.e., treatment in month 1 and control in month 2)?

Comment: Do 'treatment group' and 'target group' mean the same thing?

Comment: @mkt yes, they are same.

Comment: @MattBarstead, once you are in control group, you don't get any offers. and They can not move from target to control or vice-versa.